# How i can put a result set from a stored procedure in a temporary table in DB2

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, resultset

The title is very descriptive i think... My scenario is the next. I need to put the result of a result set (for example a result set with 6 columns and variable rows) from a stored procedure in some temporary table to make some operations over this new table.
I find some examples in the web but nothing in DB2...
The big problem is how to populate that new table with the restult set of a called stored procedure

Comment: What version of DB2 are you running, and on what operating system?

Answer (score 0):

DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE probably accomplishes what you want.  You can create this type of temporary table inside a stored procedure. It is visible only to the current session and is cleaned up for you when the session ends.

Comment: Yeah... I know how can create the table... The big problem is how to populate that new table with the restult set of a called stored procedure... If you can answer that you can be my hero! ... Thanks in advice